# Does TCP sliding / congestion window shrink if connection is idle?

Tags: tcp

If so, are there any reasonable guesses an application can make, or better yet an API call, to determine how long of idling causes the window to shrink?

Do applications that need low-latency send unnecessary traffic periodically when idle to preserve the window size?

Another way to phrase the question -- what does Google do (other than avoiding tcp itself and using just ip / udp)?

Comment: This is both off-topic and not a real question. Why would it shrink either of those windows? What makes you think this issue even exists?

Comment: Hardly off-topic unless there is a tcp/ip forum I didn't know about. And, not just real but a precise technical question. The issue of how quickly a TCP connection comes up to speed or adjusts to changed conditions is the perennial networking questions.

Comment: That said, to elaborate on why it might shrink the window (I think there is just one window adjusted two different ways but that's a different question). There are two different goals: flow-control and congestion-control/avoidance. For flow-control it makes sense to not touch the window because if the remote server could consume at a certain rate before it is reasonable to default to the same rate later. However for congestion-control, the level of congestion could have changed. If the network was not congested the, but might be congested now, it would make sense to shrink window and re-adapt.

Comment: 1. It is off-topic unless it has some relationship with actual computer programming, i.e. code that you can write. 2. You need to decide whether you are talking about one window, as per your question, or two windows as per your comments. 3. The congestion window is a function of failed sends. If there are no sends there is no reason to adjust it.

Comment: 1. I can write code that sends non-essential traffic if idle to maintain the window size if the answer is that the window shrinks. if the answer is that the window shrinks, I do not need to write that code.  2. My question and comment are pretty clear that there is 1 window to the best of my knowledge -- it is only your comment that mentioned 2 windows "either of those windows", i have never heard of SO asking people to "decide what they believe" when that is not germane to the coding question (part "1.") which remains regardless of how many windows. 3. now that's a step towards an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC2581] recommends the following: "a TCP SHOULD set cwnd to no more
   than RW [the initial window] before beginning transmission if the TCP
   has not sent data in an interval exceeding the retransmission
   timeout."
The retransmission timeout will probably be on the order of a few round trip times, so you would need to maintain a pretty high rate of sending to avoid this.  That is assuming the implementation you are using is following this recommendation.  I am not sure what common practice is today.

If you control the platform, you can probably set this with tcp configuration parameter.  On Linux: tcp_slow_start_after_idle
Note, however, that turning it off may result in excessively large bursts after idle.  When sending is active, the send window will be full, so new segments are metered into the network only on ack arrival.  After an idle period, you will be allowed to fill the window in a single burst.